# separate one column value having comma as delimiter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

How can we separate one column value having comma as delimiter using Ampscript.
Example : We have 
hello, world in ABC Data Extension in Column "Name"
I want to separate both of them using Ampscript.
As a result, put hello in column "ID" and world in column "Name".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [BuildRowSetFromString](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm). It basically creates a rowset from a String using a delimiter.

You should use something like:

```
%%[
Set @queryparams = BuildRowsetFromString(@ColumnValue,',')
for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@queryparams) do
Set @row = Row(@queryparams, @i)
Set @value = Field(@row,1)
]%%
```

You can then use `@value` values in your `UpdateData` or `UpdateDE` depending on the context (Landing page or Email).

Comment: This did not work.